# Getting an error that cannot create entityManager while trying to use Spring Data JPA with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

I am currently working on a POC to use Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA.

I want to fetch a record from the db using Spring Data JPA.

I am getting the below error

> Error creating bean with name 'bookRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defined

Here are my configration class:

```
package com.boot.configration;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationStarter {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    }

}
```

Below is my reposatory

```
package com.boot.configration;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
    public Iterable<Book> findBooksByAuthor(@Param("author") String author);
}
```

And this is my controller

```
@RestController
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    protected BookRepository bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/isbn")
    @ResponseBody
    public String book() {
        Book book = bookRepository.findOne("2222222");
        return "Book Name is = " + book.getTitle()+ " "  + "Author is = " + book.getAuthor();
    }

}
```

In the POM.xml i have the following dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BOOT</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <name>SpringBootProject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please help me to solve this error

Comment: Try dropping `@EnableJpaRepositories` and let me know what happens

Comment: Also show your pom.xml

Comment: Hi when i dropped then my BookController (Where i had autowired BookReposatory) then i got this error :

Comment: Ok, please post your pom :)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.boot.configration.BookRepository com.boot.configration.BookController.bookRepository; : No qualifying bean of type [com.boot.configration.BookRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: Please put the dependencies in the question for everyone to see :)

Comment: i appologize for the wrong formats , please check the question now i have put the pom in it

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Do you have your code on GitHub or can I download it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using spring-boot 1.0.2.RELEASE?

Comment: Yes i tried this also. However again the same exception came that you have no bean as entity manager factory. You need to define the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. When i did this then it worked fine. However can you please suggest ways of not have to explicaitly define the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. as in is there a way wherein boot configures this for us ?

Comment: Hi yes sure i can.. can you please give me your mail id so that i can mail u

Comment: It would be better to put it in github so everyone can see. If that's not possible send it to dsyer@gopivotal.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing database driver dependency.
As if you are using posgress you need to provide the driver jar.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```